# dockerTools.buildImage removes environment variables of fromImage image, how to preserve Env?

Tags: docker, nix

I expect [this variables](https://github.com/LnL7/nix-docker/blob/93d877076e8ca67273a77f0bec69b931811649c8/default.nix#L65) to be preserved when I use `dockerTools.buildImage`

```
$ docker run -it lnl7/nix:latest env
PATH=/root/.nix-profile/bin:/run/current-system/sw/bin
HOSTNAME=52be36e10f96
TERM=xterm
MANPATH=/root/.nix-profile/share/man:/run/current-system/sw/share/man
NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=/nix/store/d7r0qlms9w7k0m5kmvinp52abxbncafv-nixpkgs-unstable-2018-01-13
GIT_SSL_CAINFO=/nix/store/dblcx21khkizv3h9n0haqbkmzig3n3wd-nss-cacert-3.33/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
SSL_CERT_FILE=/nix/store/dblcx21khkizv3h9n0haqbkmzig3n3wd-nss-cacert-3.33/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
HOME=/root
```

But using this

```
$ cat runner/nixops_runner.nix
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

let
  workdir = "/app";

  sshConfig = writeText "ssh_config" ''
    Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    IdentityFile /ssh/id_rsa
  '';

  nixFromDockerHub = dockerTools.pullImage {
    imageName = "lnl7/nix";
    imageTag = "latest";

    # this hash will need change if the tag is updated at docker hub
    sha256 = "031xba6yi72v87v560wqbcsi80hqbwx498qz5b5jxigj36yb3k36";
  };
in

dockerTools.buildImage {
  name = "nixops_runner";

  fromImage = nixFromDockerHub;
}
```

I get this

```
$ docker load --input $(nix-build runner/nixops_runner.nix --no-out-link) && docker run -it nixops_runner env
Loaded image: nixops_runner:latest
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=9d673e788746
TERM=xterm
HOME=/root
```

How to preserve environment variables of image?

Comment: pullImage does not preserve Env too https://pastebin.com/FcdX61bt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [supported](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/87253) since May 2020 on Nixpkgs `master` and `nixos-unstable` and will be part of `nixos-20.09`

Older versions required setting the `config.Env` parameter to `buildImage` manually when the parent was updated. This is now automatic.

Comment: Thaks for note, but its not exactly what I wanted

Comment: It is supported in recent versions of nixpkgs now